# What type of asp.net core MVC element I have to create for a Phone field?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have a phone field like below in my **asp.net core Razor Page**. I created three input fields like below and I can see the model populated.

`<input asp-for="Phone1" />
<input asp-for="Phone2" />
<input asp-for="Phone3" />`

[image]

I want to convert this control to a re-usable control like **asp.net web form user control**. I looked at the following two options, but these types of components are read only and can't bind an `input` tag to a model.

1. View Component
2. Tag helper

How would I create a phone component that can be reused on other razor pages?

Answer (score 1):

Create a ViewModel that will contain each of the properties for your object.

> ~/ViewModels/Shared/PhoneNumberViewModel.cs

```
public class PhoneNumberViewModel
{
    public string Phone1 { get; set; }
    public string Phone2 { get; set; }
    public string Phone3 { get; set; }
}
```

Next is to create the View of the component. If this is going to be used on a form you will want to create this template in the "EditorTemplates" folder. This will give the inputs their associated "name" that will be needed when posting the data to the controller. If you are just simply displaying this information, then I would create the template in the "DisplayTemplates" folder.

> ~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/PhoneNumber.cshtml

```
@Model PhoneNumberViewModel

<label>Phone</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone1) - @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone2) - @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone3)
```

Now that you have your template, make sure to add that component as a property of your ViewModel that you want to use it with. I am going to use the HomeViewModel as example

> ~/ViewModels/Home/HomeViewModel.cs

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public HomeViewModel()
    {
         PhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber();
    }

    public PhoneNumberViewModel PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure to instantiate the object if it isn't already in the controller. The PhoneNumber object should be taken care of because it's created inside the HomeViewModel's constructor.

> ~/Controllers/HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index() 
    {
        var vm = new HomeViewModel();

        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

Then finally in the view itself, just call the EditorFor and pass in your PhoneNumber object.

> /Views/Home/Index.cshtml

@Model HomeViewModel

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.PhoneNumber)
```

Note: if you created the template in the "DisplayTemplates" instead of the "EditorTemplates" you will need to use @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.PhoneNumber) instead. Basically the built in MVC helper function knows what folder to look in based on the function you use.